# Why does storage metrics show size is smaller than the database

Tags: 2010, storage

In "Site Collection Administration : Storage Metrics" I can see our top two sites are 88384.3MB and 23324.6 MB however our database file (the mdf) is only 53GB. Any idea why this might be so much smaller?

Under sql-server configuration manager FILESTREAM is not enabled. All my searches seem to just find people with the opposite problem.

When I go to this page I see the message:

> "Data shown on this page may not be up-to-date. Future visits to this
>   page may contain more accurate results. If you are still experiencing
>   problems please contact your site administrator."

So I guess there must be some job that calculates this that is not running or failing but I cant find anything in central administration?

Any advice is appreciated. I want to backup this database offsite and need to be sure it contains all the data for the sites.

Comment: Looks like no one helped you on this.  I have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can crosscheck site collection size by opening it in SharePoint designer -> Total Storage used.
For Site collection's content database, [you can try
Powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spcontentdatabase.sites.aspx).

```
Get-SPContentDatabase -Site SiteURL
```

This returns the content database, that contains the site collection at SiteURL .